# If $B$ is an algebra, $X \subseteq B$ and $A$ the smallest subset that extends $X$, then $A= \bigcup_{n < \omega} A_n$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, universal-algebra

I need to prove the next thing:

Let $\textbf{B} = \langle B, (b_i)_{i \in I}, (g_j)_{j\in J} \rangle$. Let $X \subseteq B$ and let $A$ be the smallest subset of $B$ which extends $X$ and is closed in $\textbf{B}$. Then $A= \bigcup_{n < \omega} A_n$ where $A_0 = X \cup \{ b_i : i \in I\}$ and $A_{n+1}= A_n \cup \bigcup_{j \in J}g_j[A^{n_j}_n]$.

So, I know I need to prove both inclusions.

For the first one, $ \bigcup_{n < \omega} A_n \subseteq A$. I need to do it by induction, $A_n \subseteq A$. Let $A_0 = X \cup \{ b_i : i \in I\}$, but I don't know how to justify that it is. I mean, it "clearly" is a subset, because of the way it is constructed, but I don't know how to formally explain that, I would really appreciate the help. 
Now, As inductive hypothesis, assume $A_n \subseteq A$. As $A_\{n+1\}= A_n \cup \bigcup_{j \in J}g_j[A^{n_j}_n]$. Again, I have the notion: I know that $A_n$ is a subset by hypothesis, and I know that the other elements are also part of the subset because of the form it has, but again, I am stuck when I try to write it in a formal way, and I feel like I might be missing details.

For the other part of the inclusion, I have that $A \subseteq \bigcup_{n < \omega} A_n$. As $\bigcup_{n< \omega} A_n$ is a closed subset of $B$, and it contains $X$, it implies that $A \subseteq \bigcup_{n< \omega} A_n$, but in this case I know I'm missing on the details, but I have issues figuring them out. I would really appreciate your help in working this proof out. I'm working on improving my writing abilities so I really appreciate input on how to express things the best way possible. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First recall the definition of **closed**: A subset $A \subseteq B$ is closed in $\def\B{\mathbf B}\B$ if

> (1) $b_i \in A$ for $i \in I$.

That is $A$ contains all constants of the algebra $\B$.

> (2) $g_j[A^{n_j}] \subseteq A$ for all $j \in J$, here $n_j$ is the arity of the operation $g_j$, that is $g_j \colon B^{n_j} \to B$.

That is $A$ is closed under all operations $g_j$.

To show that $A_0 \subseteq A$, note that as $A$ is closed, we have $\{b_i \colon i \in I\} \subseteq A$ by (1) above, as $X \subseteq A$ by definition of $A$ we have $A_0 \subseteq A$.

Now suppose $A_n \subseteq A$. By (2) above, for each $j \in J$ we have $g_j[A_n^{n_j}] \subseteq g_j[A^{n_j}] \subseteq A$, as $A_n \subseteq A$, we have $A_{n+1} = A_n \cup \bigcup_j g_j[A_n^{n_j}] \subseteq A$.

For the other inclusion, your idea is right: If we can show $\bigcup_n A_n$ is closed in $\B$, we are done (as $\bigcup_n A_n$ contains $X$ and $A$ is the smallest closed subset which contains $X$).
For (1), note that for each $i \in I$, we have $b_i \in A_0 \subseteq \bigcup_n A_n$. For (2), let $j \in J$ and $a_1, \ldots, a_{n_j} \in \bigcup_n A_n$. Then there are natural numbers $k_l$ such that $a_l \in A_{k_l}$ for each $l$. Let $ k = \max_l k_l$. As $(A_n)$ is increasing, we have $a_l \in A_k$ for each $l$. But now 
$$ g_j(a_1, \ldots, a_{n_j}) \in g_j[A_k^{n_j}] \subseteq A_{k+1} \subseteq \bigcup_n A_n $$
hence $\bigcup_n A_n$ is closed.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer, it was very clear and the way you stated things helped me not only understand what had to be done, but also the right way to express it.